# Can't delete a functions namespace

Tags: triggers, cloud, trigonometry, cloud-object-storage

I've created a Functions namespace in order to test COS triggers, I've already delete all triggers and functions but when I try to delete the namespace I receive this message 
"Namespace deletion not possible due to existing COS triggers. Delete the COS triggers of this namespace and try again.."

How can I delete de COS triggers?

Thanks in advance